# Inheritance in Selenium not showing correct test count

Tags: inheritance, selenium-webdriver

I tried to test my inheritance skill with Selenium.  After creating package called MailAccess I have 3 classes under MailAccess package-

1. VisitPage class (main)
2. VerifyTitle class (extends VisitPage)
3. VerifyUsername class (extends VerifyTitle)

   public class VisitPage {
           public static FirefoxDriver f= new FirefoxDriver();

   ```
           @Test
       public void testURL() {
           f.get("https://www.mail.com");
       }


   public class VerifyTitle extends VisitPage {

       @Test
       public void testTitle(){

           super.testURL();
           String title=f.getTitle();
           Assert.assertTrue(title.contains("email"));
           System.out.print(title);
       }
   }

   public class VerifyUsername extends VerifyTitle {

       @Test
       public void testUserName(){

           super.testTitle();
           f.findElement(By.id("login-button")).click();
           f.findElement(By.id("login-email")).sendKeys("jnuit11%mail.com");

           //code below to get sendKeys value
           WebElement w= f.findElement(By.id("login-email"));
           String emailID= w.getAttribute("value");
           System.out.println("Email id used " + emailID);

           if(!(emailID).contains("@")){
               System.out.println("Invalid character");
           }
       }
   }
   ```

**Problem:** When I run it (right click on Package name>Run as> TestNG Test), this is what I see

```
Free email accounts | Register today at mail.comEmail id used jnuit11%mail.com
Invalid character
PASSED: testUserName
PASSED: testURL
PASSED: testURL
PASSED: testURL

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
```

**Question:** Why 4 tests when I have only 3 and 3 have same name as testURL?

Comment: It is a bad question, I am calling the methods which is why this is happening. I should close this.